# why page 2 not working in wp query

Tags: php, wordpress

Why http://localhost/wp/?paged=2 and older not working in wp_query?

I have movie and series from "custom post type" more than 15 posts. 
It's separated in 2 pages in the front-end, but when I press the older post, the page is still first page.

Here is my index.php loop code:

```
<?php
$paged = ( get_query_var('page') ) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
$query_args = array(
    'post_type' => array('post','series','movie'),
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'paged' => $paged
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $query_args );
?>

<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

    <h1><?php the_title();?></h1>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<div class="col-md-12">
    <?php if ($the_query->max_num_pages > 1) { // check if the max number of pages is greater than 1    ?>
        <nav class="prev-next-posts">
            <div class="prev-posts-link">
                <?php echo get_next_posts_link( 'Older Entries', $the_query->max_num_pages ); // display older posts link ?>
            </div>
            <div class="next-posts-link">
                <?php echo get_previous_posts_link( 'Newer Entries' ); // display newer posts link ?>
            </div>
        </nav>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php else: ?>
    <article>
        <h1>Sorry...</h1>
        <p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
    </article>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution:

```
    add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_get_posts' );

    function my_get_posts( $query ) {

        if ( $query->is_main_query() &&  is_home()  ) {
            $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'movie', 'series' ) );
        }
        if ( $query->is_main_query() &&  is_category()  ) {
            $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'movie', 'series' ) );
        }
        if ( $query->is_main_query() &&  is_search()  ) {
            $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'movie', 'series' ) );
        }
        if ( $query->is_main_query() &&  is_tag()  ) {
            $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'movie', 'series' ) );
        }
        return $query;
    }
```

this code isn't stop appearing navigation menu

Comment: as long as my answer was not the right answer , you will may need to confirm your answer as the correct one, so in the future in case of any visitor come to your question he could got the solution easily